# RSA key pairing between docker-airflow container and SFTP server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rsa, airflow, sftp

I'm trying to use do some `SFTP` operation with [airflow in a docker container](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow) using **docker-compose**, LocalExecutor.

From my host machine I can easily connect to the SFTP because I have [created the rsa](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/keygen/), wrote it in the default **~/.ssh** folder, and paired that with the SFTP host. How can I do the same in my docker container?
Since I don't have any rsa machine paired between my docker container and the SFTP host, I received this error, visible in the SFTPOperator logs:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/sftp_operator.py", line 124, in execute
    with self.ssh_hook.get_conn() as ssh_client:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/ssh_hook.py", line 193, in get_conn
    client.connect(**connect_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 446, in connect
    passphrase,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 677, in _auth
    key_filename, pkey_class, passphrase
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 586, in _key_from_filepath
    key = klass.from_private_key_file(key_path, password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 235, in from_private_key_file
    key = cls(filename=filename, password=password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 55, in __init__
    self._from_private_key_file(filename, password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 175, in _from_private_key_file
    data = self._read_private_key_file("RSA", filename, password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 307, in _read_private_key_file
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/.ssh/id_rsa'
```

In **Airflow Connections**, I cannot find the option SFTP in the **Conn Type** field, but I have noticed that the sftp_default connection has no entry for Conn Type. Should I also have no entry for my custom one or should I have (maybe) **SSH type**?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as it might be useful to someone else.

I solved this by creating brand new rsa keys that I copied into the container at build time and installing openssh-server into the container.
Another thing not to forget is making sure to have the same Fernet Key in both the container and the host machine.